# Merging DataFrame with aditional column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Given DataFrames:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"Question Skill": ["Algebra", "Patterns"],
              "Average": [56,76],
              "SD": [45,30]})

b = pd.DataFrame({"Question No.": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  "Question Skill": ['Algebra', 'Patterns', 'Algebra', 'Patterns', 'Patterns']
```

Below is the required output:

```
c = pd.DataFrame({"Question Skill": ["Algebra","Patterns"],
                  "Question No.": [[1,3],[2,4,5]],
                  "Average": [56,76],
                  "SD": [45,30]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanna create a function if you want to do more question skill categories, but for just 2 categories, this should be sufficient

```
algebra=[b['Question No.'][i] for i in range(len(b)) if b['Question Skill'][i]=='Algebra']
patterns=[b['Question No.'][i] for i in range(len(b)) if b['Question Skill'][i]=='Patterns']

a['Question No.']=[algebra, patterns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done in SQL style with some additional processing mixed in.

```py
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Question Skill": ["Algebra", "Patterns"], "Average": [56, 76], "SD": [45, 30]}
)

b = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Question No.": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "Question Skill": ["Algebra", "Patterns", "Algebra", "Patterns", "Patterns"],
    }
)

c = (
    pd.merge(a, b, how="left", on=["Question Skill"])
    .groupby("Question Skill")["Question No.", "Average", "SD",]
    .agg(lambda x: list(set(x))[0] if len(list(set(x))) == 1 else list(set(x)))
    .reset_index()
)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
  Question Skill Question No.  Average  SD
0        Algebra       [1, 3]       56  45
1       Patterns    [2, 4, 5]       76  30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate `Question No.` column to list in `b` first, then map the result to `a`

```py
a['Question No.'] = a['Question Skill'].map(b.groupby("Question Skill")["Question No."].apply(list))
```

```
print(a)

  Question Skill  Average  SD Question No.
0        Algebra       56  45       [1, 3]
1       Patterns       76  30    [2, 4, 5]
```